# Microsoft graph API: /me/drive/root/search - can't add filters to query

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to make search request for my OneDrive files with some specific extensions. Only solution I've got right now is to filter out after received response but that's not what I'm looking for.
Query I tried:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='book filetype:xlsx OR filetype:xls OR filetype:svg OR filetype:json OR filetype:txt')
```

Unfortunately it's not returning anything.

Comment: AFAIK, the search endpoint will search the keyword like 'book' with all the extensions and give the driveItem objects as response. You need to filter it on your end which extension you like to pick by writing the code.

Comment: Moving this to answer. If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the search endpoint will search the keyword like 'book' with all the extensions and give the driveItem objects as response. You need to filter it on your end which extension you like to pick by writing the code. Please raise a feature request in [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the Product team may implement it in future.